# Using Python Class for EDA and Pandas DataFrame cleaning. Output of the class is not a dataframe, what command will output a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, class

I am trying to use a class to clean up my script and put all of my dataframe cleaning into it.
What I have so far:

```
class DataFrame:
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df
     
    def care(self):
        df[['sign', 'care']] = df['sign'].str.split(' ', n = 1, expand = True)
        df['sign'] = df['sign'].str.strip('but ')
        df['sign'] = df['sign'].str.replace('&rsquo;', '\'')
        df['sign'] = df['sign'].astype('str')
        df['sign'] = df['sign'].str.replace('None', 'did not answer')
        df['sign'] = df['sign'].str.replace('and it matters a lo', 'it matters a lot')
        df['sign'] = df['sign'].str.replace('and it\'s fun to think abo', 'it\'s fun to think about')
        df['sign'] = df['sign'].str.replace('nan', 'did not answer')


class_test = DataFrame(df)
print(class_test)
```

The output of this is `<__main__.DataFrame object at 0x000001420AEAF7F0>`. I need the output to be a dataframe for future EDA.

I am not too familiar with classes, the code worked fine outside of the class but just for the sake of having clean code, I figured I would give it a shot.

Comment: Instead of creating your own class named `DataFrame` (confusing to me, as this is the same name as the pandas DataFrame), could you simply define and use the `care` function directly, without your own class?

Comment: Yes, and I actually have it working like that at the moment. I have 10 or 12 functions that are cleaning various columns of the dataframe, but I am trying to compartmentalize them so that I can close the `DataFrame` class and not see them if that makes sense. 

I also am just trying to get a little more experience with using classes and figuring out their function. This seems to be the only reason to use a class for me, because I can use modules and functions to do the same things as classes... Not sure about that though.